# Find equation of line $L$ such that rea of paralellogram is least

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

A line $L$ through $(4,3)$ cuts two lines $L_1 \equiv 3x+4y+5=0$ and $L_2 \equiv 3x+4y+15=0$ at $A$ and $B$ respectively. From Point $A$ a perpendicular to $L$ is drawn to meet $L_2$ at $C$ and at $B$ a perpendicular to $L$ is drawn to meet $L_1$ at $D$. Now Paralellogram $ACBD$ is completed. Find Equation of $L$ such that area of Paralellogram is Least

My Try: we have height of Paralellogram as distance between lines $3x+4y+5=0$ and $3x+4y+15=0$ which is $2$

Since height is constant for area to be least base should be minimum.

so if we assume slope of $L$ as $m$ then its equation is $y-3=m(x-4)$ that is $mx-y+3-4m=0$

Solving $L$ and $L_1$ we get point $A$ and solving $L$ and $L_2$ we get point $B$ both in terms of $m$.

Measure distance $AB$ which is another height of paralellogram.

So area is $$\Delta =\frac{h_1h_2}{\sin \theta}$$

so $\Delta$ is a function of $m$ and use differentiation to minimize. But i ts very lengthy to solve in this approach. Any better way?

Comment: Draw a diagram! Since L can point in any direction, imagine it sweeping the plane and see what happens to the parallelogram as it sweeps.

Comment: Is "Least"? The miminum area will be zero for $y=-4/3x-7/3$ which is perpendicular to both $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Comment: If $ \phi $ is the angle the line $ L $ makes with the two lines and $ d $ is the distance between the lines then the length of the base is $ {d} {tan \phi } +  \frac {d} {tan  \phi} $ This is a min at $ {tan \phi} = 1 $ or $ {+} \frac  { \pi } {4} $ or $ { - } \frac {\pi} {4} $ (using the AM-GM Inequality and condition for equality).  This angle and the angle/slope of the two lines should give the slope of $ L $. There are two possible lines $ L $.

Comment: but whats wrong with comment by @hyprfrcb

Comment: hyprfrcb's solution gives the parallelogram max area of infinity, as points C and D are at infinity. You can see this if you try to draw the lines to give points C and D. The base of the parallelogram is CB (or AD) and the height is 2. CB is actually the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle. You can temporarily ignore the point (4,3) and rotate the triangle ACB keeping A fixed. CB will go from a minimum, when the angles are 45, 45 and the fixed angle of 90,  to infinity. Knowing this, just draw lines through (4,3) at 45 degrees to L1 and L2.

Comment: @kieran: Not so: hyprfcb's solution gives the minimum area of 0. As I said, draw the diagram and sweep the line L around its fixed point and you will see what is going on.

Comment: @kieran: your formula $ base = d\tan\phi + {d\over{\tan\phi}}$ is wrong.

Comment: The perpendiculars are drawn to line $ L $. You would be correct if they were drawn perpendicular to $ L1 $ or $ L2 $. When you sweep $ L $ around, the perpendiculars to $ L $ enlarge the parallelogram area so that it is the whole area between $ L1 $ and $ L2 $ at max. This happens when $ L $ is perpendicular to $ L1 $ and $ L2 $. The area is a min when the two halves of the parallelogram are 45, 45, 90 triangles. Another max happens when $ L $ is almost parallel to $ L1 $. The min is between these.

Comment: @kieran: Right you are - I misread the question.

Comment: Looking at the angles in this. There are two possible lines $ L $. Each is at an angle $ 45^{0} $ to lines $ L1 $ and $ L2 $. To get the slope of $ L $ you need the angle $ L $ makes with the $ X $ axis . Angles in a triangle sum to $ 180^{0} $. So, one angle with the $ X $ axis is $ \frac {3 \pi} {4} + arctan(\frac {3} {4} )$. Another is $ \frac {\pi} {4} + arctan(\frac {3} {4})  $. Using the formula for $ tan(u+v) $ one slope for $ L $ is $ \frac {-1} {7} $ and the other is $ 7 $. So, the two lines $ L $ are perpendicular.